# Ctrl-c does not stop Python script on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying out [a python tutorial](https://github.com/DexterInd/Raspberry_Pi_Speech/blob/master/speak_count.py) on the raspberry pi, and have found that more often than not, `CTRL+C`, or selecting `shell > interrupt execution` from the menu, will not stop a running script.

I do get a warning when I close the entire window: `your program is still running, do you want to kill it?`, but it looks like the script even runs when the window is closed, because the cursor changes into an hourglass for all python windows.

How can I force stop a python script on raspberry?

Comment: try that https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104825/102601

Comment: This is my script: https://github.com/DexterInd/Raspberry_Pi_Speech/blob/master/speak_count.py

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the command `ps -ax | grep python` in command line to find the process id of your script. Once you find that, kill that process using this command `sudo kill <process_id>`

Comment: If `sigspec` is not provided to kill it will by default send a terminate signal which may not be any more authoritative than a `keyboardinterrupt` (depending on where in the execution of the code you are). sending `sudo kill -SIGKILL <pid>` will immediately kill the process, but it's not possible to release resources gracefully or clean up child processes.